# Haskell merge sort implementation

Tags: sorting, haskell, mergesort

I am trying to solve this question:
Define a recursive function msort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] that imple-
ments merge sort, which can be specified by the following two rules:
 Lists of length  1 are already sorted;
 Other lists can be sorted by sorting the two halves and merging the
resulting lists.

But I am having a hard time understanding how exactly the code of merge sort work.

here is my code ::

```
merge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge [] [] = []
merge (x:xs) (y:ys) | y > x =  (x:xs) ++  (y:ys)
                    |otherwise =  (y:ys) ++  (x:xs)


msort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
--base case , if length less than or equal 1 , then list is already  sorted
msort [] = [] -- how to implement base case?
msort (x:xs)  = merge  (take (length(x:xs) `div` 2 ) (x:xs)) (drop (length(x:xs) `div` 2 ) (x:xs))
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: You can pattern match on a list of length exactly one with `msort [x] = ..` or `msort (x:[]) = ..`. Alternatively you can add a catch-all case *after* the `(x:xs)` case, e.g. `msort x = x`

Comment: @user2407038 Adding a catch-all case after `(x:xs)` won't work, though, since that already catches all lists with length >= 1, including `[x]`.

Comment: @chi Indeed, the recursive case would then have to be changed to `(x:y:xs)`.

Answer (score 4):

Your `merge` function has two issues.

i) Patterns are not exhaustive: If precisely one of the lists is empty, there's no match. You should have

```
merge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge [] ys = ys
merge xs [] = xs
merge (x:xs) (y:ys) = something
```

ii) Your `something` is not actually merge sorting, it is looking at the heads and concatenates the two lists based on the comparison of the heads. For instance, if given `[1,4,5]` and `[2,3,4]`, `1` would be bound to `x`, `2` to `y`, and then since `y > x` holds, then it would return `[1,4,5,2,3,4]`, clearly unsorted, though the two given lists were sorted.

Imagine the merging as follows. Given two lists, you see only the heads, and pick the smaller one. In place of the one you removed, the next element rolls in, and you keep doing the same thing. This is a recursive process; after each pick, you do the same thing. In code:

```
merge (x:xs) (y:ys) | x < y     = x : merge xs (y:ys)
                    | otherwise = y : merge (x:xs) ys
```

As for the actual sorting `:: Ord a => [a] -> [a]`, you must also work with halves that are already sorted, which also calls for recursion:

```
msort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
msort []  = []
msort [x] = [x]
msort xs  = merge firstHalfSorted secondHalfSorted
     where firstHalfSorted  = msort . fst $ halves
           secondHalfSorted = msort . snd $ halves
           halves           = splitAt halfPoint xs
           halfPoint        = length xs `div` 2
```

Comment: While this works, there are some efficiency problems. First, you should only `splitAt halfPoint xs` once, not twice; as it is, you're potentially doubling the splitting work. Second, all those `length` calculations are kind of expensive: a whole extra `n * log n`. You can either get the length at the beginning and use `quotRem` recursively, use a tortoise-and-hare algorithm to split the lists, or switch to a bottom-up mergesort.

Comment: A lazy tortoise-and-hare splitter looks like this: `half :: [a] -> ([a], [a]); half xs0 = go xs0 xs0 where go t [] = ([], t); go t [_] = ([], t); go (t : ts) (_:_:hs) = case go ts hs of ~(front,rear) -> (t : front, rear)`

Comment: @dfeuer I fixed the duplicate `splitAt`.

Comment: I just realized a *non-lazy* tortoise-and-hare splitter is probably a better fit.

Answer (score 1):

Because I can't resist a challenge, here's an efficient, incremental, stable top-down mergesort. The same design with a couple minor tweaks should produce an efficient (but non-incremental) mergesort for a strict language; laziness is only used in the `merge` function, so it should be possible to do some juggling to avoid it if desired.

```
{-# language BangPatterns #-}

import Control.Monad

-- Divide a list into the first n `quot` 2 elements and
-- the rest. The front of the list is reversed.
half :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
half = join (go []) where
  go front ts [] = (front, ts)
  go front ts [_] = (front, ts)
  go front (t:ts) (_:_:hs) = go (t:front) ts hs

-- Some care is required to make the sort stable.
merge :: Ord a => Bool -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge _ [] ys = ys
merge _ xs [] = xs
merge up xxs@(x : xs) yys@(y : ys)
  | (if up then (<=) else (<)) x y = x : merge up xs yys
  | otherwise = y : merge up xxs ys

msort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
msort = go True where
  go _ [] = []
  go _ xs@[_] = xs
  go !up xs = merge up frontSorted rearSorted where
    frontSorted = go (not up) front
    rearSorted = go up rear
    (front, rear) = half xs
```

---

A version that uses laziness more heavily is considerably easier to write and understand, but may be susceptible to a [subtle space leak](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/2607) if care is not taken to control certain compiler optimizations:

```
-- Split a list in half, with both halves in order
half :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
half = join go
  where
    go t [] = ([], t)
    go t [_] = ([], t)
    go (t : ts) (_:_:hs) = (t : front, rear)
      where (front, rear) = go ts hs -- Interesting laziness

merge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge [] ys = ys
merge xs [] = xs
merge xxs@(x:xs) yys@(y:ys)
  | x <= y    = x : merge xs yys
  | otherwise = y : merge xxs ys

msort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
msort []  = []
msort [x] = [x]
msort xs  = merge (msort front) (msort rear)
  where (front, rear) = half xs
```

For completeness, I should mention that *bottom-up* mergesort seems rather more natural in Haskell.